# multilevel inheritance and accesing properties

Tags: c++

*On this code, why can't I give value directly to the D class if D has all the  public properties of A,B,C.*

```
class A
{
public:
  string name;    
};

class B: public A
{
public:
  string grade;
};

class C: public B
{
public:
  int age;
};

class D: public C
{
public:
  int val;   
};

// *this is giving an error called can't use dot on type.*
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{     
  class D;
  // *this part below is throwing an error.* 
  D.val=2;
  D.age=3;
  D.grade="good";
  D.name="ABC";
}
```

Comment: Are you instantiating the class? That is, creating some variable `D myD;`? It appears you're using the class name instead of an instance name.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you don't want `class D;`. You want to create an instance of the `D`:

```
D myD;

myD.val=2;
myD.age=3;
myD.grade="good";
myD.name="ABC";
```

That should work.